# Remove QueryString Variable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very beginner With Programming...(unfortunately)

I want to remove Any added QueryString To Address after i get the variables. for example:

www.websiteName.com/page.aspx?a=344&b=233

i will get a and b and after that i want my address to look like this:

(www.websiteName.com) .

"root location".

any help...

thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for which you need to pass parameters in URL(using GET method) when you are using asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var queryString = Request.QueryString;
// Handle querystring, then redirect to root
Response.Redirect("~/");
Response.End();
```

You will *have* to reload the page. When changing the URL, you are making another request to the server.

Comment: But then he will have to handle keeping state for the variables that were passed in, as redirect will reload the page, so, a cookie may be needed.

Comment: Thanks for replay..i will do it in PageLoad() event...i don't want to reload the page agin..

Comment: You will *have* to reload the page. When changing the URL, you are making another request to the server.

Comment: i want to re-write the url address without nivgating to it!.

Comment: What you want is impossible, but you could use javascript to handle parameters after a `#`-sign. This will not make another request. You can get and set these parameters using `document.location.hash`.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath()` is not made for this purpose. You can't change the url without creating a new request.

Comment: @samih if my post answered your question, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/get-absolut-url-of-asp-net-application/) on retrieving the URL of an ASP.Net application. Simply add the page name after the result.

This [blog](http://stephensulzberger.wordpress.com/2008/01/20/aspnet-modify-the-request-query-string/) describes how to manipulate the query string to redirect to the same page with different (or no) parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use

```
Request.UserHostName
```

Comment: This will get the DNS name of the remote client, not the root path of the web-site.